# acquire inside a try block

Tags: python, locks

I'm working on an open source intermediate Python book and going over a number of PEPs. In [PEP310](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0310/), there is an old proposal for "with" statements. The proposal was eventually rejected, but the following statement struck me: "Another common error is to code the "acquire" call within the try block, which incorrectly releases the lock if the acquire fails."

Could someone elaborate on how putting the acquire inside the try changes things? To my understanding, acquire calls in Python just return a boolean indicating whether the lock was successfully acquired, so how does putting it inside a try block change things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what it's referring to:

```
try:
    lock.acquire()
finally:
    lock.release()
```

If `acquire()` raises an exception, `release()` will be called, even though `acquire()` didn't succeed.  Calling `release()` on a lock which isn't currently locked may raise another exception, i.e. an exception that is only indirectly related to the root of the problem.

The correct way to write the block would either be to use `with`, or:

```
lock.acquire()
try:
    ...
finally:
    lock.release()
```

You should always code to cater for exceptions, regardless of whether the documentation suggests that a call raises one or not.  There's nothing to stop the behaviour changing in future.

Comment: OP's point is that at least `threading.Lock.acquire` doesn't raise (or at least isn't documented to).

Comment: @delnan That is not a reason to code incorrectly.  Assume that any call can raise an exception.

Comment: Yes, but only an exception raised before the lock is acquired will lead to the described error. And *some* assumptions that *some* operations are save *have* to be made.

Comment: @delnan I don't see why the OP is so sure `Lock.acquire` won't raise an exception.  The boolean result is nothing to do with failure of the call under exceptional circumstances.

Comment: For starters, the documentation says so, and changing that would probably considered a significant change in behavior which either introduces a new API entirely, or is widely announced long beforehand. Plus, if you're writing Python 2 code it's moot as it's in feature freeze.

Comment: @delnan this question is not about that specific implementation of a lock. Have another look at the PEP linked by the OP.

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes, but the example uses "locks", which I can only assume refers to the stdlib's version of locks.

Comment: I think moooeeeep has pointed out the flaw in my reasoning. I made the same assumption as delnan and went over the documentation for the acquire calls I could find in the Python docs. I was unable to find any that explicitly raised exceptions under certain circumstances, but I see how the PEP may not be limited to the locks described in the Python standard documentation. I agree with delnan that you can't take every possible undocumented failure into account, but it does make sense as a best practice (if you're not using a with block, which didn't exist in that PEP yet).